# Capture request body using Opentelemetry in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, instrumentation, open-telemetry

I am trying to capture response body using otel-instrumentation-http and responseHook. But it doesn't capture the response body sent by the server.

tracing.js

```
// OTel
const { Resource } = require('@opentelemetry/resources');
const {
  SemanticResourceAttributes,
} = require('@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions');
const {http_1} = require('http');
// SDKs
const { NodeTracerProvider, ConsoleSpanExporter, SimpleSpanProcessor } = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node');

// Instrumentation
const { HttpInstrumentation } = require('@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http');
const { registerInstrumentations } = require('@opentelemetry/instrumentation');
const { ExpressInstrumentation } = require('@opentelemetry/instrumentation-express');

// Exporters
const { OTLPTraceExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http');
const exporter = new OTLPTraceExporter({
  url: 'http://localhost:4318/v1/traces'
});

const initialize = function(config) {
  const provider = new NodeTracerProvider({
    resource: new Resource({
      [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]:
            config.serviceName,
    }),
  });
  // export spans to console (useful for debugging)
  provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(new ConsoleSpanExporter()));
  // export spans to opentelemetry collector
  provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter));

  provider.register();
  registerInstrumentations({
    instrumentations: [
      new HttpInstrumentation({
        responseHook: (span, response) => {
          response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            if(!response['myBody']){
              response['myBody'] = [];
              response['myBody'].push(chunk);
            }
            else{
              response['myBody'].push(chunk);
            }
          });
          response.on('end', () => {
            const responseBody = Buffer.concat(response['myBody']).toString();
            console.log('respnse body is', responseBody);
            console.log('response headers are', response.headers);
            span.setAttribute('http.response.body',responseBody);
            span.setAttributes('http.response.headers', response.headers);

          });
        }
      }),
      new ExpressInstrumentation({
        ignoreLayersType: ['router', 'middleware'],
        requestHook: (span, requestInfo) => {
          span.setAttribute(
                'http.request.request_body',
                JSON.stringify(requestInfo.request.body)
          );
          span.setAttribute(
                'http.request.query_params',
                JSON.stringify(requestInfo.request.query)
          );
        }
      })
    ]
  });

};

module.exports = {initialize};
```

app.js

```
const { initialize } = require('./tracing');
initialize({serviceName: 'api-observability-orchestrator'});
const express = require('express');

const port = process.env.PORT || '8080';
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, resp) => {
    resp.send({ message: 'Hello World !!' });
});

app.get('/path/:name', (req, resp) => {
    resp.send({ message: `Hello ${req.params.name}  !!` });
});

app.get('/query', (req, resp) => {
    resp.send({ message: `Hello ${req.query.name}  !!` });
});

app.post('/payload', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ requestBody: req.body });
});

app.listen(parseInt(port, 10), () => {
    console.log('Listening for requests on localhost:', port);
});
```

I have looked at the docs, and similary github issue: [github-3104](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues/3104)tried instrumenting by adding listeners inside the library function _traceClientRequest itself.

Output:

```
respnse body is {"partialSuccess":{}}
response headers are {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  date: 'Fri, 27 Jan 2023 16:02:17 GMT',
  'content-length': '21'
}
```

Expectation

```
<actual response body>
```

Comment: it is the way to catch request body, not response body, but worth to check the approach https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/discussions/3446#discussioncomment-4869098